# Unresolved Problem including Dakota.v.6.10: Undefined reference in Teuchos_as.hpp even though header files exist

Tags: compiler-errors, shared-libraries, undefined-reference, trilinos

Within the past days I have tried to install Dakota v. 6.10 on my Ubuntu 16.04 system.
According to the dakota.6.10 user manual inclusion of the library into my code works as the following:

```
\# include "LibraryEnvironment.hpp" 'front end'
\# include "DirectApplicInterface.hpp" 'back end'
```

as I try to compile, the g++ compiler throws the following error:

> ***"/usr/local/dakota/include/Teuchos_as.hpp  in line. 438: undefined reference to `Teuchos::TestForException_incrThrowNumber()"***

Same error occurs on several lines : line 438, 443, 448, 553, 563, 570

In Teuchos_as.hpp the method Test_For_Exception() is used several times, though only within the lines mentioned above reference is undefined.

**During cmake installation the following packages and libraries have been found:**

```
C-Compiler GNU 5.4.0
Cxx-Compiler GNU 5.4.0
Fortran-Compiler GNU 5.4.0
Perl 5.22.1
Python 2.7.12
MPI_C, MPI_CXX, MPI_Fortran version 3.0
boost 1.58
cmake --version 3.14.0
cmake_c-, cmake_cxx-compiler 5.4
libblas.so libraryname blas_win32
liblapack.so library name lapack_win32
```

I have tried to install trilinos-library externally and then link it to dakota cmake installation. Though this will cause other problems during installation process. In this case I use trilinos/teuchos packages are used which come along with the dakota.6.10.src installation directory.

Could you please give me any advice on how to fix this issue.
Are there maybe other global parameters that have to be set so inclusion works properly?

*** Console error Output*** similar output for all other calls of the method "Test_For_Exception()"

```
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++  -o "SGV"  ./src/LossModel/BlockageModelAungier.o  ./src/Blade.o ./src/BladeGen.o ./src/BladeSec.o ./src/Blader.o ./src/CGNSexport.o ./src/CSMgenerator.o ./src/ConsoleOut.o ./src/DakotaInterface.o ./src/DataContainer.o ./src/Grid.o ./src/GridGenerator.o ./src/MisesInterface.o ./src/MisesInterfacePost.o ./src/NACAgenerator.o ./src/Nodes.o ./src/PlotData.o ./src/Profile.o ./src/ProfileGenerator.o ./src/ReadFile.o ./src/S1Interface.o ./src/S1SectionPerformance.o ./src/SGV.o ./src/SgvKernel.o ./src/StreamData.o ./src/StreamSec.o ./src/Streamer.o ./src/TraceInterface.o ./src/WriteData.o ./src/spline.o   -lsisl -lpython2.7
./src/DakotaInterface.o: In function `double Teuchos::(anonymous namespace)::stringToReal<double>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, double (*)(char const*, char**), char const*)':
/usr/local/dakota/include/Teuchos_as.hpp:553: undefined reference to `Teuchos::TestForException_incrThrowNumber()'
/usr/local/dakota/include/Teuchos_as.hpp:553: undefined reference to `Teuchos::TestForException_getThrowNumber()'
/usr/local/dakota/include/Teuchos_as.hpp:553: undefined reference to `Teuchos::TestForException_break(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/local/dakota/include/Teuchos_as.hpp:563: undefined reference to `Teuchos::TestForException_incrThrowNumber()'
/usr/local/dakota/include/Teuchos_as.hpp:563: undefined reference to `Teuchos::TestForException_getThrowNumber()'
/usr/local/dakota/include/Teuchos_as.hpp:563: undefined reference to `Teuchos::TestForException_break(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/local/dakota/include/Teuchos_as.hpp:570: undefined reference to `Teuchos::TestForException_incrThrowNumber()'
/usr/local/dakota/include/Teuchos_as.hpp:570: undefined reference to `Teuchos::TestForException_getThrowNumber()'
/usr/local/dakota/include/Teuchos_as.hpp:570: undefined reference to `Teuchos::TestForException_break(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
./src/DakotaInterface.o: In function `float Teuchos::(anonymous namespace)::stringToReal<float>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, float (*)(char const*, char**), char const*)':
makefile:46: recipe for target 'SGV' failed
```

***These are the header files*** , I have excluded all unnecessary code parts, error lines suit lines in which "Test_For_Exception" gets called.

*** Teuchos_as.hpp***

```
#ifndef TEUCHOS_AS_HPP
#define TEUCHOS_AS_HPP

#include "Teuchos_ConfigDefs.hpp"
#include "Teuchos_Assert.hpp"
#include <limits>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cerrno>
#include <climits>

#ifdef HAVE_TEUCHOS_COMPLEX
#include <complex>
#endif // HAVE_TEUCHOS_COMPLEX

#ifdef HAVE_TEUCHOS_QD
#include <qd/qd_real.h>
#include <qd/dd_real.h>
#endif // HAVE_TEUCHOS_QD

namespace Teuchos {

namespace { // anonymous

  /// Helper function for converting the given \c std::string to an
  /// integer of type <tt>IntType</tt>.
  ///
  /// \tparam IntType A built-in integer type, like \c int or \c long.
  ///   It may be signed or unsigned.
  ///
  /// \param t [in] The string to convert.
  ///
  /// \param rawConvert [in] A function with the same arguments as
  ///   strtol, strtoul, strtoll, or strtoull, which returns
  ///   <tt>IntType<tt>.  It must return the same type as
  ///   <tt>IntType</tt>.  Note that all of these but strtol require
  ///   C99 support.  It's up to you to pick the right function for
  ///   <tt>IntType</tt>.
  ///
  /// \param intTypeName [in] Human-readable string which is the name
  ///   of <tt>IntType</tt>.
  template<class IntType>
  IntType
  intToString (const std::string& t,
               IntType (*rawConvert) (const char*, char**, int),
               const char* intTypeName)
  {
    // We call the "raw" conversion function instead of using
    // std::istringstream, because we want more detailed information
    // in case of failure to convert.  I have no idea what
    // operator>>(std::istream&, unsigned long long&) does if it
    // encounters an integer too long to fit in IntType, for example.
    //
    // mfh 13 Nov 2012: It's fair to assume that if you have "long
    // long", then your implementation of the C standard library
    // includes strtoul().  Ditto for "unsigned long long" and
    // strtoull().  If this is not the case, we could include a
    // configure-time test for these functions(), with a fall-back to
    // an std::istringstream operator>> implementation.
    char* endptr = NULL;
    // Keep the pointer, because std::string doesn't necessarily
    // guarantee that this is the same across calls to c_str(), does
    // it?  Or perhaps it does...
    const char* t_ptr = t.c_str ();
    // We preset errno to 0, to distinguish success or failure after
    // calling strtoull.  Most implementations of the C standard
    // library written with threads in mind have errno be a macro that
    // expands to thread-local storage.  Thanks to the Linux
    // documentation for strtol ("man 3 strtol", Red Hat Enterprise
    // Linux 5) for advice with the following checks.
    errno = 0;
    const IntType val = rawConvert (t_ptr, &endptr, 10);

    const IntType minVal = std::numeric_limits<IntType>::min ();
    const IntType maxVal = std::numeric_limits<IntType>::max ();
    TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION(
      errno == ERANGE && (val == minVal || val == maxVal),
      std::range_error,
      "Teuchos::ValueTypeConversionTraits<" << intTypeName << ", std::string>::convert: "
      "The integer value in the given string \"" << t << "\" overflows " << intTypeName << ".");
    TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION(
      errno != 0 && val == 0,
      std::invalid_argument,
      "Teuchos::ValueTypeConversionTraits<" << intTypeName << ", std::string>::convert: "
      "The conversion function was unable to convert the given string \"" << t << "\" to " << intTypeName << ".");
    TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION(
      endptr == t_ptr, // See above discussion of c_str().
      std::invalid_argument,
      "Teuchos::ValueTypeConversionTraits<" << intTypeName << ", std::string>::convert: "
      "The conversion function was unable to read any integer digits from the given string "
      "\"" << t << "\".");
    return val;
  }
  /// \brief Convert the given string to a RealType floating-point number.
  ///
  /// Helper function for converting the given \c std::string to a
  /// real-valued floating-point number of type RealType.
  ///
  /// \tparam RealType The real-valued floating-point type of the
  ///   return value.  We always assume that RealType is default
  ///   constructible and that <tt>operator>>(std::istream&,
  ///   RealType&)</tt> is defined.  We also assume that <tt>t !=
  ///   0</tt> is a well-formed Boolean expression for t of type
  ///   RealType.
  ///
  /// \param t [in] The string to convert.
  ///
  /// \param rawConvert [in] If not NULL, this must be one of the
  ///   following C standard library functions: strtod, strtof, or
  ///   strtold.  (strtof and strtold require C99 support.)  In that
  ///   case, we use this function to read the value from the input
  ///   string.  If NULL, we use <tt>operator>>(std::istream&,
  ///   RealType&)</tt> to read the value from the string (via
  ///   std::istringstream).
  ///
  /// \param realTypeName [in] Human-readable string which is the name
  ///   of RealType.
  template<class RealType>
  RealType
  stringToReal (const std::string& t,
               RealType (*rawConvert) (const char*, char**),
               const char* realTypeName)
  {
    if (rawConvert == NULL) {
      std::istringstream in (t);
      RealType out;
      in >> out;
      return out;
    }
    else {
      char* endptr = NULL;
      // Keep the pointer, because std::string doesn't necessarily
      // guarantee that this is the same across calls to c_str(), does
      // it?  Or perhaps it does...
      const char* t_ptr = t.c_str ();
      // We preset errno to 0, to distinguish success or failure after
      // calling strtoull.  Most implementations of the C standard
      // library written with threads in mind have errno be a macro that
      // expands to thread-local storage.  Thanks to the Linux
      // documentation for strtod ("man 3 strtod", Red Hat Enterprise
      // Linux 5) for advice with the following checks.
      errno = 0;
      const RealType val = rawConvert (t_ptr, &endptr);

      TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION(
        errno == ERANGE && (val != 0),
        std::range_error,
        "Teuchos::ValueTypeConversionTraits<" << realTypeName
        << ", std::string>::convert: "
        "The value in the given string \"" << t << "\" overflows "
        << realTypeName << ".");
      //
      // mfh 20 Nov 2012: Should we treat underflow as an error?
      //
      TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION(
        errno == ERANGE && val == 0,
        std::invalid_argument,
        "Teuchos::ValueTypeConversionTraits<" << realTypeName
        << ", std::string>::convert: "
        "The value in the given string \"" << t << "\" underflows "
        << realTypeName << ".");
      TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION(
        endptr == t_ptr, // See above discussion of c_str().
        std::invalid_argument,
        "Teuchos::ValueTypeConversionTraits<" << realTypeName
        << ", std::string>::convert: "
        "The conversion function was unable to read any floating-point data "
        "from the given string \"" << t << "\".");
      return val;
    }
  }

} // namespace (anonymous)


} // end namespace Teuchos
```

*** Teuchos_Assert.hpp***

```
#ifndef TEUCHOS_ASSERT_HPP
#define TEUCHOS_ASSERT_HPP


#include "Teuchos_TestForException.hpp"


/** \brief This macro is throws when an assert fails.
 *
 * \note <tt>The std::exception</tt> thrown is <tt>std::logic_error</tt>.
 *
 * \ingroup TestForException_grp
 */
#define TEUCHOS_ASSERT(assertion_test) TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPT(!(assertion_test))

#ifdef TEUCHOS_DEBUG
/** \brief Behaves as TEUCHOS_ASSERT only if debugging is enabled.
 *
 * \ingroup TestForException_grp
 */
#define TEUCHOS_DEBUG_ASSERT(assertion_test) TEUCHOS_ASSERT(assertion_test)
#else
#define TEUCHOS_DEBUG_ASSERT(assertion_test)
#endif


/** \brief This macro asserts that an integral number fallis in the range
 * <tt>[lower_inclusive,upper_exclusive)</tt>
 *
 * \note <tt>The std::exception</tt> thrown is <tt>std::out_of_range</tt>.
 *
 * WARNING: This assert will evaluate <tt>index</tt>,
 * <tt>lower_inclusive</tt>, and <tt>upper_inclusive</tt> more than once if
 * there is a failure which will cause the side-effect of an additional
 * evaluation.  This is needed because the return types of these values are
 * unknown.  Therefore, only pass in arguments that are objects or function
 * calls that have not side-effects!
 *
 * \ingroup TestForException_grp
 */
#define TEUCHOS_ASSERT_IN_RANGE_UPPER_EXCLUSIVE( index, lower_inclusive, upper_exclusive ) \
  { \
    TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION( \
      !( (lower_inclusive) <= (index) && (index) < (upper_exclusive) ), \
      std::out_of_range, \
      "Error, the index " #index " = " << (index) << " does not fall in the range" \
      "["<<(lower_inclusive)<<","<<(upper_exclusive)<<")!" ); \
  }


/** \brief This macro is checks that to numbers are equal and if not then
 * throws an exception with a good error message.
 *
 * \note The <tt>std::exception</tt> thrown is <tt>std::out_of_range</tt>.
 *
 * WARNING: This assert will evaluate <tt>val1</tt> and <tt>val2</tt> more
 * than once if there is a failure which will cause the side-effect of an
 * additional evaluation.  This is needed because the return types of
 * <tt>val1</tt> and <tt>val2</tt> are unknown.  Therefore, only pass in
 * arguments that are objects or function calls that have not side-effects!
 *
 * \ingroup TestForException_grp
 */
#define TEUCHOS_ASSERT_EQUALITY( val1, val2 ) \
  { \
    TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION( \
      (val1) != (val2), std::out_of_range, \
      "Error, (" #val1 " = " << (val1) << ") != (" #val2 " = " << (val2) << ")!" ); \
  }


/** \brief This macro is checks that an inequality between two numbers is
 * satisified and if not then throws a good exception message.
 *
 * \note The <tt>std::exception</tt> thrown is <tt>std::out_of_range</tt>.
 *
 * WARNING: This assert will evaluate <tt>val1</tt> and <tt>val2</tt> more
 * than once if there is a failure which will cause the side-effect of an
 * additional evaluation.  This is needed because the return types of
 * <tt>val1</tt> and <tt>val2</tt> are unknown.  Therefore, only pass in
 * arguments that are objects or function calls that have not side-effects!
 *
 * \ingroup TestForException_grp
 */
#define TEUCHOS_ASSERT_INEQUALITY( val1, comp, val2 ) \
  { \
    TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION( \
      !( (val1) comp (val2) ), std::out_of_range, \
      "Error, (" #val1 " = " << (val1) << ") " \
      #comp " (" #val2 " = " << (val2) << ")! FAILED!" ); \
  }


#endif // TEUCHOS_ASSERT_HPP
```

*** Teuchos_TestForException.hpp***

```
#ifndef TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION_H
#define TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION_H

/*! \file Teuchos_TestForException.hpp
\brief Standard test and throw macros.
*/

#include "Teuchos_TypeNameTraits.hpp"
#include "Teuchos_stacktrace.hpp"


namespace Teuchos {


/*! \defgroup TestForException_grp Utility code for throwing exceptions and setting breakpoints.
\ingroup teuchos_language_support_grp
*/

/** \brief Increment the throw number.  \ingroup TestForException_grp */
TEUCHOSCORE_LIB_DLL_EXPORT void TestForException_incrThrowNumber();

/** \brief Increment the throw number.  \ingroup TestForException_grp */
TEUCHOSCORE_LIB_DLL_EXPORT int TestForException_getThrowNumber();

/** \brief The only purpose for this function is to set a breakpoint.
    \ingroup TestForException_grp */
TEUCHOSCORE_LIB_DLL_EXPORT void TestForException_break( const std::string &msg );

/** \brief Set at runtime if stacktracing functionality is enabled when *
    exceptions are thrown.  \ingroup TestForException_grp */
TEUCHOSCORE_LIB_DLL_EXPORT void TestForException_setEnableStacktrace(bool enableStrackTrace);

/** \brief Get at runtime if stacktracing functionality is enabled when
 * exceptions are thrown. */
TEUCHOSCORE_LIB_DLL_EXPORT bool TestForException_getEnableStacktrace();

/** \brief Prints the message to std::cerr and calls std::terminate. */
TEUCHOSCORE_LIB_DLL_EXPORT [[noreturn]] void TestForTermination_terminate(const std::string &msg);


} // namespace Teuchos


#ifdef HAVE_TEUCHOS_STACKTRACE
#  define TEUCHOS_STORE_STACKTRACE() \
  if (Teuchos::TestForException_getEnableStacktrace()) { \
    Teuchos::store_stacktrace(); \
  }
#else
#  define TEUCHOS_STORE_STACKTRACE()
#endif


/** \brief Macro for throwing an exception with breakpointing to ease debugging
 *
 * \param throw_exception_test [in] Test for when to throw the exception.
 * This can and should be an expression that may mean something to the user.
 * The text verbatim of this expression is included in the formed error
 * string.
 *
 * \param Exception [in] This should be the name of an exception class.  The
 * only requirement for this class is that it have a constructor that accepts
 * an std::string object (as all of the standard exception classes do).
 *
 * \param msg [in] This is any expression that can be included in an output
 * stream operation.  This is useful when buinding error messages on the fly.
 * Note that the code in this argument only gets evaluated if
 * <tt>throw_exception_test</tt> evaluates to <tt>true</tt> when an exception
 * is throw.
 *
 * The way that this macro is intended to be used is to
 * call it in the source code like a function.  For example,
 * suppose that in a piece of code in the file <tt>my_source_file.cpp</tt>
 * that the exception <tt>std::out_of_range</tt> is thrown if <tt>n > 100</tt>.
 * To use the macro, the source code would contain (at line 225
 * for instance):
 \verbatim

 TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION( n > 100, std::out_of_range,
    "Error, n = " << n << is bad" );
 \endverbatim
 * When the program runs and with <tt>n = 125 > 100</tt> for instance,
 * the <tt>std::out_of_range</tt> exception would be thrown with the
 * error message:
 \verbatim

 /home/bob/project/src/my_source_file.cpp:225: n > 100: Error, n = 125 is bad
 \endverbatim
 *
 * In order to debug this, simply open your debugger (gdb for instance),
 * set a break point at <tt>my_soure_file.cpp:225</tt> and then set the condition
 * to break for <tt>n > 100</tt> (e.g. in gdb the command
 * is <tt>cond break_point_number n > 100</tt> and then run the
 * program.  The program should stop a the point in the source file
 * right where the exception will be thrown at but before the exception
 * is thrown.  Try not to use expression for <tt>throw_exception_test</tt> that
 * includes virtual function calls, etc. as most debuggers will not be able to check
 * these types of conditions in order to stop at a breakpoint.  For example,
 * instead of:
 \verbatim

 TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION( obj1->val() > obj2->val(), std::logic_error, "Oh no!" );
 \endverbatim
 * try:
 \verbatim

 double obj1_val = obj1->val(), obj2_val = obj2->val();
 TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION( obj1_val > obj2_val, std::logic_error, "Oh no!" );
 \endverbatim
 * If the developer goes to the line in the source file that is contained
 * in the error message of the exception thrown, he/she will see the
 * underlying condition.
 *
 * As an alternative, you can set a breakpoint for any exception thrown
 * by setting a breakpoint in the function <tt>ThrowException_break()</tt>.
 *
 * NOTE: This macro will only evaluate <tt>throw_exception_test</tt> once
 * reguardless if the test fails and the exception is thrown or
 * not. Therefore, it is safe to call a function with side-effects as the
 * <tt>throw_exception_test</tt> argument.
 *
 * NOTE: This macro will result in creating a stacktrace snapshot in some
 * cases (see the main doc page for details) and will be printed automatically
 * when main() uses TEUCHOS_STANDARD_CATCH_STATEMENTS() to catch uncaught
 * excpetions.
 *
 * \ingroup TestForException_grp
 */
#define TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION(throw_exception_test, Exception, msg) \
{ \
  const bool throw_exception = (throw_exception_test); \
  if(throw_exception) { \
    Teuchos::TestForException_incrThrowNumber(); \
    std::ostringstream omsg; \
    omsg \
      << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":\n\n" \
      << "Throw number = " << Teuchos::TestForException_getThrowNumber() \
      << "\n\n" \
      << "Throw test that evaluated to true: "#throw_exception_test \
      << "\n\n" \
      << msg; \
    const std::string &omsgstr = omsg.str(); \
    TEUCHOS_STORE_STACKTRACE(); \
    Teuchos::TestForException_break(omsgstr); \
    throw Exception(omsgstr); \
  } \
}


/** \brief Macro for throwing an exception from within a class method with
 * breakpointing to ease debugging.
 *
 * \param throw_exception_test [in] Test for when to throw the exception.
 * This can and should be an expression that may mean something to the user.
 * The text verbatim of this expression is included in the formed error
 * string.
 *
 * \param Exception [in] This should be the name of an exception class.  The
 * only requirement for this class is that it have a constructor that accepts
 * an std::string object (as all of the standard exception classes do).
 *
 * \param msg [in] This is any expression that can be included in an output
 * stream operation.  This is useful when buinding error messages on the fly.
 * Note that the code in this argument only gets evaluated if
 * <tt>throw_exception_test</tt> evaluates to <tt>true</tt> when an exception
 * is throw.
 *
 * \param tfecfFuncName [implicit] This is a variable in the current scope that is
 * required to exist and assumed to contain the name of the current class method.
 *
 * \param this [implicit] This is the variable (*this), used for printing the
 * typename of the enclosing class.
 *
 * The way that this macro is intended to be used is to call it from a member
 * of of a class. It is used similarly to TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION, except that it
 * assumes that the (above) variables <tt>this</tt> and <tt>fecfFuncName</tt>
 * exist and are properly defined. Example usage is:

 \code

   std::string tfecfFuncName("someMethod");
    TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION_CLASS_FUNC( test, std::runtime_error,
      ": can't call this method in that way.");

 \endcode

 * See <tt>TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION()</tt> for more details.
 *
 * \ingroup TestForException_grp
 */
#define TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION_CLASS_FUNC(throw_exception_test, Exception, msg) \
{ \
   TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION( (throw_exception_test), Exception, \
   Teuchos::typeName(*this) << "::" << tfecfFuncName << msg ) \
}


/** \brief Macro for throwing an exception with breakpointing to ease debugging
 *
 * This macro is equivalent to the <tt>TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION()</tt> macro except
 * the file name, line number, and test condition are not printed.
 *
 * \ingroup TestForException_grp
 */
#define TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION_PURE_MSG(throw_exception_test, Exception, msg) \
{ \
    const bool throw_exception = (throw_exception_test); \
    if(throw_exception) { \
      Teuchos::TestForException_incrThrowNumber(); \
      std::ostringstream omsg; \
        omsg << msg; \
      omsg << "\n\nThrow number = " << Teuchos::TestForException_getThrowNumber() << "\n\n"; \
      const std::string &omsgstr = omsg.str(); \
      Teuchos::TestForException_break(omsgstr); \
      TEUCHOS_STORE_STACKTRACE(); \
      throw Exception(omsgstr); \
    } \
}


/** \brief This macro is the same as <tt>TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION()</tt> except that the
 * exception will be caught, the message printed, and then rethrown.
 *
 * \param throw_exception_test [in] See <tt>TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION()</tt>.
 *
 * \param Exception [in] See <tt>TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION()</tt>.
 *
 * \param msg [in] See <tt>TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION()</tt>.
 *
 * \param out_ptr [in] If <tt>out_ptr!=NULL</tt> then <tt>*out_ptr</tt> will
 * receive a printout of a line of output that gives the exception type and
 * the error message that is generated.
 *
 * See <tt>TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION()</tt> for more details.
 *
 * \ingroup TestForException_grp
 */
#define TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION_PRINT(throw_exception_test, Exception, msg, out_ptr) \
try { \
  TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION(throw_exception_test, Exception, msg); \
} \
catch(const std::exception &except) { \
  std::ostream *l_out_ptr = (out_ptr); \
  if(l_out_ptr) { \
    *l_out_ptr \
      << "\nThrowing an std::exception of type \'"<<Teuchos::typeName(except) \
      <<"\' with the error message: " \
      << except.what(); \
  } \
  throw; \
}


/** \brief This macro is designed to be a short version of
 * <tt>TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION()</tt> that is easier to call.
 *
 * \param throw_exception_test [in] Test for when to throw the exception.
 * This can and should be an expression that may mean something to the user.
 * The text verbatim of this expression is included in the formed error
 * string.
 *
 * \note The exception thrown is <tt>std::logic_error</tt>.
 *
 * \ingroup TestForException_grp
 */
#define TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPT(throw_exception_test) \
  TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION(throw_exception_test, std::logic_error, "Error!")


/** \brief This macro is designed to be a short version of
 * <tt>TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION()</tt> that is easier to call.
 *
 * \param throw_exception_test [in] Test for when to throw the exception.
 * This can and should be an expression that may mean something to the user.
 * The text verbatim of this expression is included in the formed error
 * string.
 *
 * \param msg [in] The error message.
 *
 * \note The exception thrown is <tt>std::logic_error</tt>.
 *
 * See <tt>TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION()</tt> for more details.
 *
 * \ingroup TestForException_grp
 */
#define TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPT_MSG(throw_exception_test, msg) \
  TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION(throw_exception_test, std::logic_error, msg)


/** \brief This macro is the same as <tt>TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPT()</tt> except that the
 * exception will be caught, the message printed, and then rethrown.
 *
 * \param throw_exception_test [in] See <tt>TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPT()</tt>.
 *
 * \param out_ptr [in] If <tt>out_ptr!=NULL</tt> then <tt>*out_ptr</tt> will
 * receive a printout of a line of output that gives the exception type and
 * the error message that is generated.
 *
 * See <tt>TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION()</tt> for more details.
 *
 * \ingroup TestForException_grp
 */
#define TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPT_PRINT(throw_exception_test, out_ptr) \
  TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION_PRINT(throw_exception_test, std::logic_error, "Error!", out_ptr)


/** \brief This macro intercepts an exception, prints a standardized message
 * including the current filename and line number, and then throws the
 * exception up the stack.
 *
 * \param exc [in] the exception that has been caught
 *
 * \ingroup TestForException_grp
 */
#define TEUCHOS_TRACE(exc)\
{ \
  std::ostringstream omsg; \
    omsg << exc.what() << std::endl \
       << "caught in " << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << std::endl ; \
  throw std::runtime_error(omsg.str()); \
}

/** \brief This macro is to be used instead of
 * <tt>TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION()</tt> to report an error in situations
 * where an exception can't be throw (like in an destructor).
 *
 * \param terminate_test [in] See <tt>TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION()</tt>.
 *
 * \param msg [in] See <tt>TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION()</tt>.
 *
 * If the termination test evaluates to <tt>true</tt>, then
 * <tt>std::terminate()</tt> is called (which should bring down an entire
 * multi-process MPI program even if only one process calls
 * <tt>std::terminate()</tt> with most MPI implementations).
 *
 * \ingroup TestForException_grp
 */
#define TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_TERMINATION(terminate_test, msg) \
{ \
  const bool call_terminate = (terminate_test); \
  if (call_terminate) { \
    std::ostringstream omsg; \
    omsg \
      << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":\n\n" \
      << "Terminate test that evaluated to true: "#terminate_test \
      << "\n\n" \
      << msg << "\n\n"; \
    auto str = omsg.str(); \
    Teuchos::TestForTermination_terminate(str); \
  } \
}

#endif // TEUCHOS_TEST_FOR_EXCEPTION_H
```

Answer (score 0):

Either try to install Trilinos with a >100-line make file or try a simpler approach when configuring Dakota.

```
cmake \
-D DAKOTA_HAVE_MPI:BOOL=TRUE \
-D DAKOTA_HDF5:BOOL=TRUE -D Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE:BOOL=TRUE 
$DAK_SRC
```